# Java Factorial code using for loop is not showing exact output

Tags: java, factorial

My code is not showing the exact output for generating factorial of numbers using for loop.It shows all values as 0 for all numbers .

```
public class Factorial {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int NUM_FACTS = 100;
    for(int i=1;i<=NUM_FACTS;i++) {
        System.out.println("Factorial of "+i+" is "+ `enter code here`factorial(i));
    }
}
//getting factorial of a particular number
public static int factorial(int n) {
    int result = 1;
    for(int i=2; i<n; i++)
        result *= i;
    return result;
}
}
```

Comment: That's because the `int` is overflowing. Change it to `long` or `BigInteger`

Comment: Also, an efficiency comment:  to compute N! you have started from 1, even though you already had (N-1)! available, and thus N! could be done with just one more multiplication.    Maybe that doesn't matter - it all depends on what this code is intended to show or to be used for.

Answer (score 0):

`100!` will have [24 zeros, not counting the numbers in front](https://www.mycoted.com/100_Factorial) and it will not fit into an `int` data type. Either use [`java.util.BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) or switch from calculating value to approximating it e.g. using [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) formula.

```
public static BigInteger factorial(int n) {
  BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;
  for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    result = result.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
  }
  return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(factorial(100));
}
```

will output:

```
93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works at least until a certain number `i`. Here you see a part of its output.

```
Factorial of 1 is 1
Factorial of 2 is 1
Factorial of 3 is 2
Factorial of 4 is 6
...
Factorial of 15 is 1278945280
Factorial of 16 is 2004310016
Factorial of 17 is 2004189184
Factorial of 18 is -288522240
Factorial of 19 is -898433024
Factorial of 20 is 109641728
```

As you can see from the output, the sign is going from positive to negative. This is because of the limited range of `int` - you see an overflow. Changing to `long` will not help, as its range is also not sufficient. Think about using `BigInteger`.